# invalidate files in cloudfront using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront

I want to invalidate files in `cloudfront cache`. The files are saved in `amazon S3`.

My requirement is

**When I delete a post in my application, I want delete the file in S3 and send an invalidation request to `cloudfront`.**

File delete from S3 is done. But I do not know how to send invalidation request to S3. I read about `cloudfront-invalidator` gem from https://github.com/reidiculous/cloudfront-invalidator/network/members. But I am not getting any specific example using that gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my solution using cloudfront-invalidator.

I changed as per my requirement and using it successfully..

I get problem in my rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7. So customize it and now it is successfully running

Here is the link

https://github.com/krishnasahoo/cloudfront-invalidator